# Building and running Docker images on a proxy and non-proxt environment

Tags: docker

I am trying to wrap my head around a problem with building and running a Docker image on different hosts. One host (local) does not use a proxy and the other (build-server) does.

When building the image locally, I can get all my dependencies straight from the internet but when I build it on the build server, I need to go past the proxy, or the build will fail. Same with running the container.

Is there an elegant way to make an image which builds a container that can run everywhere, regardless of the underlying environment (the core idea of Docker)?

Thanks in advance.
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documents](https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/), you can configure the client for each computer to use a different network configuration:

> If your container needs to use an HTTP, HTTPS, or FTP proxy server,
>   you can configure it in different ways:
>
> In Docker 17.07 and higher, you can configure the Docker client to
>   pass proxy information to containers automatically.
>
> In Docker 17.06 and lower, you must set appropriate environment
>   variables within the container. You can do this when you build the
>   image (which makes the image less portable) or when you create or run
>   the container.

If you configure the client, it will connect via the proxy automatically. you can also set these environment variables while building:

> HTTP_PROXY, HTTPS_PROXY, HTTPS_PROXY, FTP_PROXY, NO_PROXY

so it will be picked automatically when trying to connect the network (I did not test but it should work)